# How to write a nightwatch custom command using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, nightwatch.js

I have the following custom command written in javascript for nightwatch.js. How can I translate this to using jquery?

```
exports.command = function (classId, indexIfNotZero) {
    this.browser.execute(function (classId, indexIfNotZero) {
        if (classId.charAt(0) == '.') {
            classId = classId.substring(1);
        }
        var items = document.getElementsByClassName(classId);

        if (items.length) {
            var item = indexIfNotZero ? items[indexIfNotZero] : items[0];

            if (item) {
                item.click();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

        //alert(rxp);
    }, [classId, indexIfNotZero], function (result) {
        console.info(result);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that I see that are causing your issues.

First, you have [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) that may cause issues.  Your global export command has 2 variables (`classId` and `indexIfNotZero`) and your internal execute command has the same parameter names.

Second, for custom commands, the `this` variable is actually the `browser`.  So instead of doing `this.browser.execute`, you need to just call `this.execute`.

As for a complete working code example, here you go:

```
'use strict';

var ClickElementByIndex = function(className, index) {
  if (!index) {
    index = 0;
  }

  this.execute(function(selector, i) {
    var $item = $(selector + ':eq(' + i + ')');
    if (!!$item) {
      $item.click();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }, [className, index], function(result) {
    console.info(result);
  });
};

exports.command = ClickElementByIndex;
```

Note that you do need jQuery available in the global scope of your app for this to work.

Comment: I'm a bit ate to answer that, but `!index` condition resolves to true if index equals 0, too. It is not a problem here but for the sake of clarity `if (index === undefined)` is better.