# How can I use jquery inside Nightwatch

Tags: jquery, nightwatch.js

I have text i need to perform htmlEndcoding on in nightwatch.
I found a solution but it requires using jquery. I can't figure out how to access jquery inside of Nightwatch.

I found the following [htmlEncode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-lost-when-attribute-read-from-input-field) this looks like something I could use, but I don't know how to include it in nightwatch. I get '$' undefined. I can see this is for jquery but I don't know how to get to jquery in nightwatch.

```
function htmlEncode(value){
// Create a in-memory div, set its inner text (which jQuery automatically encodes)
// Then grab the encoded contents back out. The div never exists on the page.
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

function htmlDecode(value){
  return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}
```

I also found [How to write a nightwatch custom command using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36830349/how-to-write-a-nightwatch-custom-command-using-jquery), but it comes with the caveat:
'Note that you do need jQuery available in the global scope of your app for this to work.' ... I don't know how to do this.

I'm a java programmer and I'm new to both nightwatch and javascript. Seems like I should be able to get to jquery via the client or the api, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Tried several version of the following:

```
npm install jQuery

var $ = require('jquery');

var $ = require('jQuery');


var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom
 , myWindow = jsdom().createWindow()
 , $ = require('jQuery')
 , jq = require('jQuery').create()
 , jQuery = require('jQuery').create(myWindow)
 ;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Jquery in your web app like:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/core.js"></script>
```

then you can do:

```
const jqueryCheck = function (browser){

    browser.execute(function (data, done) {

             return $("[href!=''][href]");
    }, [e], function(e){

            browser.verify.elementPresent(e[0],"Explanation...")

    })
}
```