# Nightwatch.js e2e test how to set jQuery available at the global scope?

Tags: jquery, nightwatch.js

I am trying to use jQuery selectors with my Nightwatch.js e2e tests 
According to this answer :

[How to write a nightwatch custom command using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36830349/how-to-write-a-nightwatch-custom-command-using-jquery)

I need to have jQuery available in the global scope of my app for this to work.  ( otherwise I got into trouble with $(selector) refs ...

```
'use strict';

var ClickElementByIndex = function(className, index) {
  if (!index) {
    index = 0;
  }

  this.execute(function(selector, i) {
    var $item = $(selector + ':eq(' + i + ')');
    if (!!$item) {
      $item.click();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }, [className, index], function(result) {
    console.info(result);
  });
};

exports.command = ClickElementByIndex;
```

Comment: duplicated question see answer. at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674080/how-to-use-npm-jquery-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the jquery package as a dependency to your `package.json` and then you must require `jquery` within the file. Typically, you would have already done this for `nightwatch`. To add the package, `jquery`, as a dep, run this command from the root directory of your project:

`npm install jquery --save-dev`

Then verify it worked by checking that you have an additional line added for `jquery` to `package.json`. It will look like this:

`"devDependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.0",`

**Note:** If no `package.json` exists yet, go to the top level folder in the project and run `npm init`. After going through the prompts, you can add both `jquery` and `nightwatch` as dev-deps using the above command.

Lastly, to require `jquery` in your custom command or assertion, just add `const $ = require('jquery')` to the top of the file to assign `$` as `jquery`.